# For loop update better alternative

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, join, for-loop

In Oracle 11g, I am using the following in a ***procedure***.. can someone please provide a better solution to achieve the same results.

```
FOR REC IN 
(SELECT E.EMP FROM EMPLOYEE E 
JOIN 
COMPANY C ON E.EMP=C.EMP
WHERE C.FLAG='Y')
 LOOP
 UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FLAG='Y' WHERE EMP=REC.EMP;
 END LOOP;
```

Is there a more efficient/better way to do this? I feel as if this method will run one update statement for each record found (Please correct me if I am wrong).

Here's the is actual code in full:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE ACTION_MSC AS 
BEGIN
  -- ALL MIGRATED CONTACTS, CANDIDATES, COMPANIES, JOBS
  -- ALL MIGRATED CANDIDATES, CONTACTS
  FOR REC IN (SELECT DISTINCT AC.PEOPLE_HEX 
    FROM ACTION AC JOIN PEOPLE P ON AC.PEOPLE_HEX=P.PEOPLE_HEX 
    WHERE P.TO_MIGRATE='Y')
  LOOP
    UPDATE ACTION SET TO_MIGRATE='Y' WHERE PEOPLE_HEX=REC.PEOPLE_HEX;
  END LOOP;

  -- ALL MIGRATED COMPANIES
  FOR REC IN (SELECT DISTINCT AC.COMPANY_HEX 
    FROM ACTION AC JOIN COMPANY CM ON AC.COMPANY_HEX=CM.COMPANY_HEX
    WHERE CM.TO_MIGRATE='Y')
  LOOP
    UPDATE ACTION SET TO_MIGRATE='Y' WHERE COMPANY_HEX=REC.COMPANY_HEX;
  END LOOP;

  -- ALL MIGRATED JOBS
  FOR REC IN (SELECT DISTINCT AC.JOB_HEX 
    FROM ACTION AC JOIN "JOB" J ON AC.JOB_HEX=J.JOB_HEX
    WHERE J.TO_MIGRATE='Y')
  LOOP
    UPDATE ACTION SET TO_MIGRATE='Y' WHERE JOB_HEX=REC.JOB_HEX;
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END ACTION_MSC;
```

Comment: Please show the complete trigger code.

Comment: First Suggestion: Avoid using triggers. Do tasks programatically instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it will do one update for each record found. Looks like you could just do:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FLAG = 'Y'
WHERE EMP IN (SELECT EMP FROM COMPANY WHERE FLAG = 'Y')
AND FLAG != 'Y';
```

A single update will generally be faster and more efficient than multiple individual row updates in a loop; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/556552/266304) for another example. Apart from anything else, you're reducing the number of context switches between PL/SQL and SQL, which add up if you have a lot of rows. You could always benchmark this with your own data, of course.

I've added a check of the current flag state so you don't do a pointless update with no chamges.

---

It's fairly easy to compare the approaches to see that a single update is faster than one in a loop; with some contrived data:

```
create table people (id number, people_hex varchar2(16), to_migrate varchar2(1));
insert into people (id, people_hex, to_migrate)
select level, to_char(level - 1, 'xx'), 'Y'
from dual
connect by level <= 100;

create table action (id number, people_hex varchar2(16), to_migrate varchar2(1));
insert into action (id, people_hex, to_migrate)
select level, to_char(mod(level, 200), 'xx'), 'N'
from dual
connect by level <= 500000;
```

All of these will update half the rows in the `action` table. Updating in a loop:

```
begin
  for rec in (select distinct ac.people_hex 
    from action ac join people p on ac.people_hex=p.people_hex 
    where p.to_migrate='Y')
  loop
    update action set to_migrate='Y' where people_hex=rec.people_hex;
  end loop;
end;
/

Elapsed: 00:00:10.87
```

Single update (after rollback; I've left this in a block to mimic your procedure):

```
begin
  update action set to_migrate = 'Y'
  where people_hex in (select people_hex from people where to_migrate = 'Y');
end;
/

Elapsed: 00:00:07.14
```

Merge (after rollback):

```
begin
  merge into action a
  using (select people_hex, to_migrate from people where to_migrate = 'Y') p
  on (a.people_hex = p.people_hex)
  when matched then update set a.to_migrate = p.to_migrate;
end;
/

Elapsed: 00:00:07.00
```

There's some variation from repeated runs, particularly that update and merge are usually pretty close but sometimes swap which is faster in my environment; but both are always significantly faster than updating in a loop. You can repeat this in your own environment and with your own data spread and volumes, and you should if performance is that critical; but a single update is going to be faster than the loop. Whether you use update or merge isn't likely to make much difference.

Comment: Alex,I already upvoted you.. Just a note, that `DISTINCT` in your LOOP query will definitely consume COST, that adds to total time.

Comment: @OracleUser - yes, but there are duplicate values, so without that you'd end up updating the same rows multiple times. I'm already doing some batching; I inferred that from the question but might be wrong or have a different ratio. With a version that pulls all matching rowids and updates every row once individually, it takes about twice as long as the `distinct` version, so it's even worse.